# setTimeout function not working

Tags: javascript

This is a basic timer from 01:00 to 00:00 and when it gets to 00:00 I want to show an alert that Time is up.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7u26/1/)

To run faster I choose the second 58. 
In firebug I see that jocsecunda1 and jocsecunda2 have these values, but I don't know why setTimeount is not triggered. Maybe I am putting it in the wrong place?

Thanks!

```
//just create html, ignore:
var pentruminut = document.createElement('span');
document.body.appendChild(pentruminut);
pentruminut.setAttribute('id','unminut');
document.getElementById('unminut').innerHTML="01:00";

window.onload=function(){
(function(){
     setInterval(function(){
     cro();
     document.getElementById('unminut').innerHTML="0"+jocminut+":"+jocsecunda1+jocsecunda2;
    },1000);
    }());
}
var jocminut = 1;
var jocsecunda1 = 6;
var jocsecunda2 = 10;
function cro(){
    if(jocsecunda1!=0||jocsecunda2!=0){
        jocsecunda2 -=1;
        while(jocminut==1){
            jocminut-=1;
            jocsecunda1 -=1;
        }   
            while(jocsecunda2==-1){
                jocsecunda1-=1;
                jocsecunda2=9;

            }

    }
}
//here is the issue:
(function(){setTimeout(function(){
    if (jocsecunda1==5&&jocsecunda2==8){
        alert("Time is up");
        }
    },1000);}())
```

Comment: Your `setTimeout()` call asks that a function be run 1 second in the future, and you call that at the same time you set up the interval timer. After 1 second, the condition in the `if` statement in the timeout handler is not met, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: why you say they are declared in `window.onload()`?I closed that function before them. is it because the function cro() is called there?

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! I misunderstood how setTimeout works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setTimeout is set to run only once, with a 1000 millisecond timeout, so the check for 58 seconds is made only once when the timer is at 59 seconds.
A better solution would be to change the way your program works, and instead check when your variables `jocsecunda1 == 5` and `jocsecunda2 == 8`, and fire the alert then.

Example fildde: http://jsfiddle.net/L7u26/4/

Comment: You can read more about timing events [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).